# difference display website in same browser and same version

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, localhost

i add a website in my iis
after that when i browse this address e.g (http://localhost:8080) everything of my layout is ok,but when exchange "localhost" with my computer's ip (192.168.1.30) : e.g  (http://192.168.1.30:8080) my layout is not correct. why?
this problem started from when i published my website in server , in the server is wrong but in local in the debug mode my layout is true.
all status check in IE 8
even i delete all of the my css file but this problem is exist

Comment: do you have any check with localhost ? After that the information's you give us is nothing.

Comment: You do realise that "my computer's ip" is not the same as your example URI? One ends in 30 and the other in 45.

Comment: @MrLister i had a mistake i'm sorry, i edited

Comment: Hm. Not sure. I assume you checked your whole project for occurrences of "localhost", right? OK. If you say "in local in the debug mode my layout is true" do you mean when running in the Visual Studio, using its own built-in internet server feature?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with compatibility view I guess. By default, IE8 will load "intranet sites" (that is http://localhost/) with quirksmode rendering, as if there were no doctype at the beginning of your HTML code.

Try unchecking `Tools > Compatibility View Settings > Include intranet sites in Compatibility View` or if it doesn't work, try other methods in this MSDN topic: [IE8 formatting issues when accessing simple web page remotely](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/a8a01461-b798-4467-9633-cac04603079a/)

Note: are you testing your work with IE8 as your main browser? Please install and use Firefox (or maybe Chrome or Opera) ASAP and only use IE8 for testing the rendering on IE8 ;)